# Why does velocity becomes zero in this case

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, spring

[image]

> This is a  case in  which the system is released from rest and friction is absent everywhere and we had to find the maximum elongation of the spring.

I didn't know how to solve this question so I asked my friend and he said that this will be like the case when we had maximum  spring compression between two blocks having same velocity but I am not sure about his answer...can anyone explain the condition for maximum elongation of the spring in this case.

My effort : I know we have to apply energy conservation here and the velocity at any time will be same from constraint equation..I just need to know how the maximum and minimum velocities will be achieved in such scenarios.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with “energy conservation” it seems you know what to do...

Comment: Can you solve a weight hanging off a spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum elongation (as well as maximum compresion) occurs when block A has velocity zero. This is a universal condition that applies for all spring systems. If A is moving, then in the next instant of time the spring's length will have changed since A will have moved. But if A isn't moving, then in the next instant of time the elongation stays the same - i.e. it's a stationary point. These correspond to maximum and minimum elongation.

Comment: so velocity of A should be zero for that case and from constraint equation the velocity of the other block will be zero also so we can apply energy conservation easily,right

Comment: @harambe [This simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNk7x.gif) may help illustrate the point.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ thanks for the stimulation .It helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

The maximum elongation of the block will be 2 times the static elongation.
Because the system will oscillate from x=0 to x = 2.mg/k.

If there was friction or damping, the system would be arriving after some back and forth vibrations at equilibrium at k.x = mg and x = mg/k.